# How to build a website that targets all the keywords for which we want to rank?

Tags: keywords

So here I am a developer in an advertising agency, and I am responsible for our good reference site for search engines.

We want to put our site in connection with lots of keywords as:

- The name of the company
- Activities (we have lots of activities)
- Address (we have 4 locations in Paris, Pyon, and Italy)
- The names of our clients

How to give these keywords to Google so that it can better reference us?

For example if a customer types:

- communication agency in **italy**
- **9999-99** agency communication (such as zip code)
- website creation **Paris**
- logo*design **France**
- creating greeting card for **XXXXX** Company

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you want to hear, but... write lots of authoritative content on the topics you want to promote, featuring the keywords you are wanting to rank for. Get other authoritative sites to link to your pages using the keywords you are wanting to rank for. It really is that <del>simple</del> difficult!

> The names of our clients

This is questionable. In doing this you will be competing with your own clients which may not be desirable.